# Absolute value inequality - Please guide further

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that if the numbers $x$, $y$ are of one sign, then $\left|\frac{x+y}{2}-\sqrt{xy}\right|+\left|\frac{x+y}{2}+\sqrt{xy}\right|=|x|+|y|$.

Expanding the LHS,
$$\left|\frac{x+y}{2}-\sqrt{xy}\right|= \left|\frac{x+y -2\sqrt{xy}}{2}\right| = \frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2}{2}$$
and similarly
$$\left|\frac{x+y}{2}+\sqrt{xy}\right| = \left|\frac{ (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{2}\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

Use AM-GM to conclude $\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy}$ if $x,y > 0$ and $\frac{x+y}{2} \le -\sqrt{xy}$ if $x,y < 0.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It may be clearer if you write $x=(-1)^t2a^2$, $y=(-1)^t2b^2$ for some $a,b>0$ and $t\in\{0,1\}$.

Mouse over the gray box for more details if you get stuck.

> You now want to show that $$|(-1)^t(a^2+b^2)-2ab|+|(-1)^t(a^2+b^2)+2ab|=2a^2+2b^2.$$ Shuffling the minus signs, we get $$|a^2+b^2+(-1)^{t+1}2ab|+|a^2+b^2+(-1)^t2ab|=2a^2+2b^2.$$ Whether or not $t=0$ or $t=1$, one of the two terms on the left is equal to $$|a^2+b^2-2ab|=|(a-b)^2|=(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab,$$ and the other term is equal to $$|a^2+b^2+2ab|=|(a+b)^2|=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab.$$